# Incorporating a Canadian business with a US founder

Tags: income-tax, canada, corporation, incorporating

I'm a Canadian citizen who is a American permanent resident residing in the USA. My cofounder is a Canadian citizen residing in Canada. We are incorporating a business that will be operating in Canada (not the USA.)

What's the best way to incorporate? Should we do a Canadian Federal Corporation? Will my American residency cause issues with our Canadian corporate bank accounts? We were considering Stripe Atlas for ease of use which would set up a Delaware C-Corp.

Comment: Where will most of your customers be?

Comment: All of our customers will be in Canada. Ontario to start.